# Create Csv with loop and output

Tags: powershell

This basically works

```
foreach ($cprev in $CopyPreventeds) {
    Write-Host ("prevented copy $(($cprev)."Name")")
    $cprev | Select-Object Path, Name, Length, LastWrite, DestinationNewer | Export-Csv '.\prevented.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

But only the last output is written to the csv. How could I write all contents to a new csv with an output at the same time for the user in PowerShell.

Comment: Either add the parameter `-Append` to your `Export-Csv` command or remove it from inside the loop, save the output of the loop in a variable an pipe this variable to `Export-Csv`

Comment: `$cprev | Select-Object Path, Name, Length, LastWrite, DestinationNewer | ConvertTo-Csv | Tee-Object -FilePath '.\prevented.csv' -Append | ConvertFrom-Csv` is the easiest way I can think of without saving to a variable first.

Comment: The -Append did the Trick. Kudos if you post this as an official answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something?

While I appreciate a solution has already been proposed in the comments, I have to ask, given the narrow scope of the question why are we using an obscure, albeit clever technique? And/or, repeatedly invoking `Export-Csv`...

The question doesn't mention sparing a variable.  Moreover, There doesn't appear to be a need for the `ForEach` loop.

```
$CopyPreventeds | 
Select-Object Path, Name, Length, LastWrite, DestinationNewer | 
Export-Csv '.\prevented.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

In the above `$CopyPreventeds` already exists and remains so, unmolested after the export.  You would need only to output it again for the benefit of an interactive user.  All taking advantage of PowerShell's intuitive pipeline and features.

Moreover, since the iteration variable `$cprev` isn't needed you are still less one variable.

*Note: You don't need `-Append` because you are streaming into a single `Export-Csv` command, as opposed to repeatedly invoking it.*

There are at least 2 ways (probably many more) you could conveniently output to an interactive user.

1: Echo a header, something like "The following copies were prevented:" then echo the variable `$CopyPreventeds`, presumably to a table.

*Note: That given multiple points at which you seem only interested in a subset of properties. You may think about trimming those objects beforehand:*

```
$CopyPreventeds = 
$CopyPreventeds | 
Select-Object Path, Name, Length, LastWrite, DestinationNewer

$CopyPreventeds | Export-Csv '.\prevented.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "The following copies were prevented:"
$CopyPreventeds | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-Host
```

*Note: More than 4 Properties in a `[PSCustomObject]` (resulting from `Select-Object`) where custom formatting hasn't been defined will by default output as a list, so use Format-Table to overcome that. `Out-Host` is then used to prevent pipeline pollution.*

2: Return to using a `ForEach-Object` Loop for the output between the `Select-Object` and the `Export-Csv` command.

```
$CopyPreventeds | 
Select-Object Path, Name, Length, LastWrite, DestinationNewer 
ForEach-Object{
    "Prevented Copy : {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}" -f $_.Path, $_.Name, $_.Length, $_.LastWrite, $_.DestinationNewer |    
    Write-Host
    $_
} | 
Export-Csv '.\prevented.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

In this example, when you are done outputting to the screen (admittedly a little messy), you emit `$_` from the loop, thus piping it to `Export-Csv` just the same.

*Note: there are a number of ways to construct strings, I choose to use the `-f` operator here because it's a little cleaning than imbedding numerous `$()` sub expressions. And, of course this assume you want to prefix on every line  Which I personally think is gratuitous, so I'd choose something more like #1..*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.INdeed there was additional help !